# How can I reproduce the Windows 7 hotkeys in Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hotkeys

How can I reproduce the Windows 7 hot keys in Windows Server?

Specifically I want these two.

```
Windows logo key +Left Arrow    Maximize the window to the left side of the screen.
Windows logo key +Right Arrow   Maximize the window to the right side of the screen.
```

I tried hotkeybind but it does not have this functionality.

**Resolved thanks to Rob's comment:** 
Download [Here](http://www.aerosnap.de/eng/download.htm)

Comment: Try enabling Aero Glass...http://www.expta.com/2009/02/how-to-enable-aero-glass-on-windows.html

Comment: This feature specifically is called Aero Snap.

Comment: Well my windows look a lot better but it did not affect my hot keys. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Rob oh snap! that works like a charm, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one wants to put this in as an answer...

First, you need to install the Desktop Experience feature using Server Manager, or with the following command line:

```
ServerManagerCmd -i Desktop-Experience
```

This will install the Windows Aero and other desktop themes, along with a lot of other programs that go into Vista by default (Windows Media Player, Windows Photo Gallery, etc.).

Next, you need to set the Themes service to Automatic and start it.

If you're running Windows Server 2008 (not Windows Server 2008 R2):

```
Click Control Panel > Personalization
Click Windows Color and Appearance and select the Windows Aero color scheme
(To turn Aero off, click Theme and select the Windows Classic theme)
```

For Windows Server 2008 R2:

```
Click Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization
Click Personalization and select the Aero Theme
```